# Change DateFormat not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, view, c#-3.0, date-format

I have the following issue.

I have a field where It accepts date from the user with the code below

```
<div class="field">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ClientAcceptance.InitialSubmissionDate)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ClientAcceptance.InitialSubmissionDate, new { @class = "date" })
</div>
```

and in the website is accepting the date from a pop-up date window which you can click choose the date.

For example, when I click on 20th of February the field will take the value 20/02/2014 but when I submit, the code reads the value as "MM/dd/yyyy" instead of "dd/MM/yyyy" and will give me a "Please enter a valid date" which is normal because there is not month number 20.

This is what I have in my model

```
    [Display(Name = "InitialSubmissionDateField", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime? InitialSubmissionDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

and this is what the controler does:

```
[HttpPost]
        [PrivilegeAuthorize("id", MDM.Modules.Infrastructure.Common.Privileges.CanEditCAC)]
        public ActionResult Decision(int id, DecisionEditViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var vm = BindDecisionViewModel(id);
                    vm.ClientAcceptance = model.ClientAcceptance;
                    return View(vm);
                }
                _service.CreateOrUpdateDecision(model.ClientAcceptance);
                TempData["message"] = Resources.DecisionSavedSuccessfully;
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = model.ClientAcceptance.ClientId });
            }
            catch (BusinessServicesException ex)
            {
                TempData["message"] = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Resources.UnknownError, ex.Message);
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

I appreciate every help to resolve this.

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: Did you try changing `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]` to `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]`

Comment: Hi, I have tried but it doesnt work. thanks!